# Is there any chip that can measure temperature from the bottom of the chip with radiation?

Tags: sensor

[image]

I'm trying to find a chip that can measure temperature from B side(PCB board side). All chip that I could find is measuring temperature from A side of the chip. Is there any chip like what I described? The chip should be small, low powered.

I'm gonna use the chip for human body temperature check by putting it on to the PDMS(flexible, transparent PCB)

Comment: There's no ray, just radiation, here.

Comment: But anyway, PDMS is a plastic I didn't know worked as a PCB substrate, since I think it'll destroy far below typical solder temperatures– are you sure? Oh, wait, I think of PMMA, I only know PDMS as lubricant

Comment: Since it's WCSP, couldn't you just put it on the other side of the board?

Comment: I'm trying to make a patch type temperature sensing module. So It is not considerable to put it on the other side.

Comment: Worst case you could always mount the device it on a piggy back board that you plug into the main board.

Comment: Now, if there was such a chip, how are you planning to mount it on your PDMS? All sources I can find say the low-molecular-weight versions vaporize at 200°C, and the others get destroyed before they vaporize at temperatures above 200°C, and the solder procedures for these types of ICs require high temperatures. Can you point us to ressources on your PCB?

Comment: I can't explain how to put it on the PCB. I'm working on capstone project, and the professor who is helping my project said that it is possible. I'm not sure that it is actually PDMS, but he showed me a flexible and transparent PCB.

Comment: http://blogs.eset.com.br/laboratorio/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/flex-patch.jpg This is an image similar with what I saw.

Comment: Why not mount the chip on the bottom of the board?

Comment: If that stuff is flexible enough, you may be able to mount it topside and fold it over. Quite common with flex circuits.

Comment: If you can't have protrusion on the other side but want to mount it there then you may be able to cut a hole with the pins on two tabs that protrude into it, push the tabs up enough that the ship is flush and solder. Though unless you can form the substrate and have it keep it's shape the this would need a jig.

Comment: If you're making physical contact with the patient, why mess around with IR, rather than using a "normal" temp sensor such as a thermistor? Real cheap, high accuracy over small temp ranges (and living patients fit that description), small thermal mass means quick response. Why the radiation requirement?

Comment: @user325050 You need to write a lot more. What temperature range do you have to be able to observe? Does it need to observe the highest temperature found (hottest spot itself) through the board, air, and epoxy packaging? You said small, low power, but did you also mean to say "cheap?" Do you have a budget limit for this "test" your teacher is asking of you? I'm not sure what "patch type" means here. More explanation on that? How long are you allowed to take to make a reading? What are your constraints??? Are you completely free to imagine other than explicit, given constraints?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I would like to continue measuring the body temperature while the patient is moving. The contact type body temperature measurement chip is not considerble as disturbance caused by the movement is too big.

Comment: @jonk I'll use the chip for human body temperature check, so the range of the temperature would be 30~50 celsius. If I can get the infrared radiation from B side, it will go through PDMS and air. Small - less than 20mmX20mm, low power - less than 5V input would be enough. cheap - I'm not gonna make it twice, so just less than 50$ is enough. You can see this image to understand what "patch type" means - http://blogs.eset.com.br/laboratorio/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/flex-patch.jpg

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for the comments.

Comment: @user325050 Yeah. Thanks for the patch picture. That's what I was imagining. A bandage. But I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @user325050 You have a flat bandage. One side faces "ambient." One side faces towards something (through materials and air) else that is higher than ambient. The peak wavelength shifts about 1 micron going from 20 C to 50 C (from about 10 microns to about 9 microns, I think.) Can you use that or perhaps the far distribution tails, instead, where the differentials will be higher? Is there a wavelength that passes through epoxy and boards well? Think about emissivity, lambertian back reflectors, matte vs specular, etc. Does your training say anything useful about this situation?

Comment: There are a lot of material that are transmissive to the IR when thin.  Just mount sensor as usual and cover with a thin film to make it waterproof and remove skin contact to PCB tracks and other possible solder points.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if there is a bottom sensing device. Perhaps contact the top sensing manufacturer and ask.

However, if not and that substrate is flexible enough, you may be able to mount it topside and fold it over.

That method is used all the time with flex circuits.

[image]

Comment: As I commented above, I'm considering patch type module now. So it would be hard to use this method. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user325050 not by your picture, the material shown in that example looks extremely flexible.

Comment: I mean, one side of the substrate should be attached to human skin.

Comment: @user325050..  I KNOW! see my answer update for what  I mean. Chip topside, folded back and glued or soldered tabs.